# Maximum Supported Resolution Capable by OpenCV VideoCapture

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision

I'm wondering whether there is OpenCV documentation on VideoCapture lists compatible sensor configurations e.g. Resolution < 640x480 || FPS < 1e100. Basically I am wondering whether the class is compatible with large resolutions such as 1960x1080 or even 2304x1536, and whether there are run-time implications of this even if the height/width fields can be set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenCV provides a simple cross-platform video input API. It does not attempt to provide a comprehensive feature list, and even (some of) the properties [it does provide](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#videocapture-get), do not alwyas work with all hardware and platforms.

The whole highgui module is mostly aim at rapid prototyping and not for bulletproof video I/O. If your platform provides more advanced SDKs for image capture and configuration, you can use those SDKs and simply pass the resulting image buffers to be wrapped with `cv::Mat()`.